# Why my computer is not being recognized as a laptop?

Tags: release-juno

I have a question, and I don't know if it's a problem with my hardware or not.
The fact is that my computer is being recognized by Juno OS as a desktop computer and not as laptop. I wonder why, because everything works well and nothing is missing (battery indicator etc.).

I have a hp pavilion 13 convertible 2 in 1.
I'm not sure whether more information is needed in this case or not, waiting for answers and requests for more info about my hardware.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Convertibles were not being recognized as laptops, but were falling back to a generic "computer" icon. This has been fixed in the latest release of the icons and will show up in your "Operating System Updates" in AppCenter soon!

## Longer/technical answer

The "About" screen in System Settings uses a local service to populate some information, like the hostname and the icon name to use to represent the hardware. That service was correctly reporting `computer-convertible` as the icon name. However, our icon set did not have a `computer-convertible` icon, so it correctly fell back to use the `computer` icon, which is represented by an all-in-one type computer. We've now [added a symlink](https://github.com/elementary/icons/pull/739) from `computer-convertible` to `computer-laptop`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, you're right It has been fixed just now, I received the icon update and now it shows up in the about section. Thank you.
All in all the Juno OS is quite impressive good job Elementary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a problem, I've tried some notebook and the same goes, I think it's normal. I will continue testing on other laptops. but apparently it is normal. don't worry.

Comment: I thought that too, but wasn't sure, thank you for the answer.